# Formatting Cucumber Feature file

Tags: java, csv, gherkin, cucumber-jvm

I  extensively use Data tables in cucumber feature file. Data Tables are mostly dump of Database table which i export in pipe delimted format and not properly aligned.

Is there any option in Cucumber-JVM that will auto align DataTables ?

Comment: If you are dumping a database table into a feature file then your feature file is unlikely to be accessible to business users. You may be missing out on some of the value of Cucumber vs other tools. (or on some of the value of another tool)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using IntelliJ go to Code>Reformat code

Answer (score 2):

As [Joe says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150527/formatting-cucumber-feature-file#comment50808516_23400304), the `--autoformat` feature isn't available any more.

I found that `cucumber --dry-run --format pretty --quiet --no-color` pretty much gives you what you want, although you'd have to do some string-wrangling to write back to the files.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using IntelliJ, there is also a good plugin called [Pipe Table Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7550-pipe-table-formatter)!

:)

Answer (score 1):

```
cucumber --autoformat . -t @myuglytests


cucumber -help

   -a, --autoformat DIR             Reformats (pretty prints) feature files and write them to DIRECTORY.
                                    Be careful if you choose to overwrite the originals.
                                    Implies --dry-run --format pretty.
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this option has [been removed in Cucumber 2.0](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/issues/194). That issue references the "Gherkin CLI" which has a `reformat` command, but that CLI [was removed in v2.2.8](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/compare/v2.2.7...v2.2.8).  So it would appear that there is no longer any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I created this with a similar problem in mind. Paste your code into the editor, hit Ctrl+Enter and your table pipes will be aligned. [Tidy Gherkin Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tidy-gherkin/nobemmencanophcnicjhfhnjiimegjeo)

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse IDE you could shortcut **Ctrl + Shift + F** for 'Pretty format' in Feature files.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ
Reformat a code fragment﻿
In the editor, select a code fragment you want to reformat.

If you don't select a code fragment, IntelliJ IDEA will reformat the whole file.

Before reformatting, you can take a look at the code style settings that are applied to the selected code: press AltEnter and click Adjust code style settings.

In the main menu, go to Code | Reformat Code or press CtrlAlt
0L
.

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl + Alt + L

It works for me!! :)